# How to check Paging Memory on swap for Windows, via command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, memory, swap

On Windows operating systems, we use the Resource Monitor to check the memory paging for my server.

I need to check it via command line so I can put in my standard script to check and create text log files.

Is there a way to check the paging memory on swap for windows, but via command line?

Comment: code your own commandline tool which calls NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemPageFileInformation) to enum page files statistic and usage

Comment: Does the PowerShell command `Get-Counter '\Paging File(*)\% Usage'` give you what you need? Or `get-counter '\Process(_total)\Page File Bytes'`?

Answer (score 11):

try this:

> systeminfo | find "Virtual Memory"

this will return:

```
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  17.297 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 7.186 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    10.111 MB
```

here is my powershell script that returns swap usage:

```
$maxSizeStr = systeminfo | select-string "Virtual Memory: Max Size:"
$maxSize = [int][regex]::Matches($maxSizeStr, '[\d.]+').Value -replace "\.",""
$inUseStr = systeminfo | select-string "Virtual Memory: In Use:"
$inUse = [int][regex]::Matches($inUseStr, '[\d.]+').Value -replace "\.",""
$swapUsage = ($inUse / $maxSize) * 100
Write-Output $swapUsage
```

Comment: This returns different values than the PowerShell commands @DavidPostill suggested. Maybe running both with a just rebooted system with lots of RAM can tell which one is right

Answer (score 1):

Is my powershell script returns swap usage

```
$colItems = get-wmiobject -class "Win32_PageFileUsage" -namespace "root\CIMV2" -computername localhost 
 
foreach ($objItem in $colItems) { 
      $allocate = $objItem.AllocatedBaseSize
      $current = $objItem.CurrentUsage
} 
write-host ($allocate - $current)
```

Comment: Your answer would be better if you included some example output.